# arping not working in docker

Tags: networking, docker, arp

I'm currently trying to add a presence feature in my OpenHab installation by detecting presence of our mobile phones. For iPhone an arping is necessary, unfortunately it looks to me like arping won't work from within the docker container.
Is this generally not working from within docker containers or does anyone have an idea how I could get it working?

I already tried also host networking as well as privileged mode but nothing helps yet.

Comment: a docker container is in its own network by default. arping uses ARP which works within its network, it's not IP thus not routed. So your container must be configured to be in the same network as your iPhones. (Sorry I won't be able to tell you how, start there: https://docs.docker.com/network/)

Comment: If the reason is not about network, then your question will have to explain in what way it "won't work".